# Draw rectangle between two mouse clicks on canvas using fabric js

Tags: html, canvas, fabricjs

I am beginner to fabric js. I want to draw a rectangle over an canvas having background image. First time when user mouse down on the canvas get that co-ordinates then user mouse up then again when he mouse down then rectangle should be drawn between these points these points are the upper left point and the bottom right point. I am very much confused how to do that.

I am sharing my code which I have used to draw canvas and set background image and it also draws and line.

```
<html lang="en" >
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>HTML5 canvas - Image color picker | Script Tutorials</title>
    <link href="index.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.1.0/fabric.all.min.js" ></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="column1">
            <canvas id="panel" width="700" height="350"></canvas>
        </div>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
</body>

<script>
(function() {
    var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('panel', { selection: false });

    var line, isDown;

    canvas.on('mouse:down', function(o){
        isDown = true;
        var pointer = canvas.getPointer(o.e);
        var points = [ pointer.x, pointer.y, pointer.x, pointer.y ];
        console.log(points);

        line = new fabric.Line(points, {
            strokeWidth: 5,
            fill: 'red',
            stroke: 'red',
            originX: 'center',
            originY: 'center'
        });
        canvas.add(line);
    });

    canvas.on('mouse:move', function(o){
        if (!isDown) return;
        var pointer = canvas.getPointer(o.e);
        line.set({ x2: pointer.x, y2: pointer.y });
        canvas.renderAll();
    });

    canvas.on('mouse:up', function(o){
        isDown = false;
    });

    fabric.Image.fromURL('fedex.jpg', function (img) {
        canvas.add(img.set({
            width: 700,
            height:350,
            left: 350,
            top: 175,
            selectable: false,
        }));
    });
})();
</script>
```

Comment: Hi there. The downvote you've received may have been for requesting urgency; note that in general that just annoys the volunteer readership here. Please don't add that to your questions, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

**Modify** your code like this:

```
(function() {
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('panel');

var line, isDown, startPosition={}, rect,drawingMode=true;

canvas.on('mouse:down', function(event){
 if (!drawingMode) return;
    isDown = true;
    console.log(event.e.clientX,event.e.clientY);
    startPosition.x=event.e.clientX;
    startPosition.y=event.e.clientY;

    console.log(startPosition);

        rect=new fabric.Rect({
            left:event.e.clientX,
            top:event.e.clientY,
            width:0,
            height:0,
            stroke:'red',
            strokeWidth:3,
            fill:''
        });
        canvas.add(rect);
});

canvas.on('mouse:move', function(event){
    if (!isDown || !drawingMode) return;

     rect.setWidth(Math.abs( event.e.clientX-startPosition.x ));
     rect.setHeight(Math.abs( event.e.clientY -startPosition.y ));

    canvas.renderAll();
});

canvas.on('mouse:up', function(){
    isDown = false;
     canvas.add(rect);
});

canvas.on('object:selected', function(){
    drawingMode = false;         
});

canvas.on('object:selected', function(){
    drawingMode = false;         
});
canvas.on('selection:cleared', function(){  
    drawingMode = true;      
});

})();
```

This will draw rectangle with mouse.
[See in Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mahbub_rahman/m04c3smj/5/)

Comment: Thanks for your help.But want to make it on mouse click such as when user click at two points rectangle should be drawn along with all co-ordinates of rectangle should be display in log.

Comment: updated the fiddle to  avoid the offset between  mouse position and coordinates http://jsfiddle.net/asturur/m04c3smj/7/